# Codeigniter+phpstorm external library autocomplete?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, phpstorm

I'm just trying phpStorm with codeigniter.

I was looking for autocompletition so I found https://github.com/topdown/phpStorm-CC-Helpers

I did it and it works great !

Then I installed the Stencil library for codeigniter.

The library works great but I haven't any autocomplete with it...

I added "* @property CI_Stencil $stencil" in /system/core/model.php, controler.php and in CI_phpStorm.php in the root folder.

Does someone have an idea why I got autocompletition with the core function of Codeigniter but not with the added libraries ?

Thx !

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem, and I was able to get it to work by adding

```
* @property Stencil $Stencil
```

to MY_Controller